# alias of function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

when we have :

```
           int functon1(int a, int b);
           int function2(int a, int b);
           .....

           typedef int (*callback) (int,int);

           struct gate{
                  char name[50];
                  callback fptr;
                  };
```

Where did we give and alias with typedef and what the callback fptr is?
Is (int ,int ) an alias to (*callback)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in this statement

`typedef int (*callback) (int,int);`

`/* now callback can be used as a type */`

You are typedefing a function pointer. Here `callback` is a function pointer which can point to any function, that functions has to take two argument of `int` type and returns `int`

Next time when you do like

`callback fptr;`

that means `fptr` is **function pointer** and that can point to any function who satisfies `callback` declaration properties.

Next when you initializes `fptr` like this

`struct gate var;`

`var.fptr = sum; /* here sum is the function which adds 2 int and returns int */`

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` is used for defining a new type.
What this `typedef int (*callback) (int,int);` means is that you are defining a new type named `callback`. You can use this type to define variables. A variable having the type `callback` is actually a pointer to a function which takes two `int`s and returns an `int`.

This explanation applies to your `struct gate` inside which you define `fptr` to be of type `callback`.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function1(int a, int b);
int function2(int a, int b);

typedef int (*callback) (int,int);

struct gate{
     char name[50];
     callback fptr;
};


int main(void) {
    struct gate g;
    g.fptr = function1;
    printf("The sum is: %d\n", g.fptr(4, 5));
    return 0;
}

int function1(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Running the above program shows:
`The sum is: 9`